Proof that uniform convergence with pointwise convergent derivatives mean we can interchange limits
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $C^1([0,1])$, where $f_n \to f$ in $C^0$ (with sup norm) and $f_n' \to g$ pointwise for some continuous $g$. Must $\int_0^t g(x) dx = f(t)-f(0)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$? This subsequently proves that $g\equiv f'$.
The issue is that I don't even see how to show $f'_n$ is even uniformly bounded, so I can't convert this into the Lebesgue integrals and then apply BCT or DCT.
I know in general pointwise convergence is not powerful enough to make sure integrals converge. I am now inclined to think there is a counterexample.
EDIT: I previously said this had to be true because the book says so, but I misunderstood my book. I think in my book $f'_n\to g$ uniformly in which case we definitely have $\int_0^t f'_n(x) dx \to \int_0^t g(x) dx$

You need the uniform convergence of $f'_n$ and the pointwise convergence in at least one point of $f_n$

Thanks! Can you give me a counterexample?

More precisely, I want the following: let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of functions in $C^1([0,1])$, where $f_n \to f$ in $C^0$ (with sup norm) and $f_n' \to g$ pointwise for some continuous $g$, and $\int_0^t g(x) dx \ne f(t)-f(0)$

@psl2Z I don't know why, but I computed the limit as $x\to \infty$ of $f'_n$. Time to go to sleep
